# Can not install EMI design rule checker in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, emc, install

I want to install the EMI design rule checker in my Altium Designer 22.6.1 but there is no such extension in my extension list. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does Altium (capital 'A') not have a support forum or helpdesk?

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com